# Directory '.' is not installable. Neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip

Yes, I checked previously asked questions with same subject but could not get answer (sorry for being noob).

I also cloned the repo and placed it under /Lib/site-packages folder but I guess it needs to be added to /.idea/workspace.xml file too though not sure how to do that (using PyCharm as ide).

I am trying to add https://github.com/Talha-Tariq/poptions to my project but getting the error while I try to install it using pip.  I could not find the files (either setup.py or pyproject.toml) in the public repo of poptions.  Please suggest how to address this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is no pypi package for poption and the way you should use it is just... copy the `poptions` directory to your project. With that way you can just use `import poptions` in your code (assuming you copy the directory visible by your PYTHONPATH).

Ah and do not forget to install `poptions` requirements with `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Comment: I added to my project (/Lib/site-packages folder) and when I call one of its method (callCreditSpread()), I am getting error as below

AttributeError: module 'poptions' has no attribute 'callCreditSpread'

Comment: My guess is you copied all repository instead of just `poptions` directory. In such case your import line should be `import poptions.poptions as poptions` or `from poptions.poptions.callCreditSpread import *`. Let me know it that was the problem.

Comment: BlackScholes.py, CallCreditSpread.py and other python files are under /Lib/site-packages/poptions folder (and not /Lib/site-packages/poptions/poptions folder).  

Just for testing purpose, I did import as mentioned above (import poptions.poptions as poptions) but got import error as well.

Comment: I have two more guesses. 1) poptions has no `__init__.py`, try to add it. 2) Not sure how the path to site-packages should look like on windows, but make sure `Lib/site-packages` is indeed the first place that contains `poptions` directory in the `sys.path` : `python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"`

Comment: importing like `from poptions.CallCreditSpread import *` works.  I also had to add `poptions.` in imports of CallCreditSpread.py (as below).

`from numba import jit
from poptions.MonteCarlo import monteCarlo
import time
from poptions.BlackScholes import blackScholesCall
import numpy as np`
 
Unsure if its best solution or not but I am good as long as it works :)

Thanks for looking into the issue and helping with suggestions and solution!